# How to jump to React Ckeditor 5 paragraph from outside bookmark link?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

In website I have a React Ckeditor 5 editor field with article. Article comments (like bookmarks) are outside the field. When I click on comment, I want to jump into current article paragraph.
Ckeditor has to scroll to current paragraph position.

Ckeditor has inline comments plugin, but it is too expansive.

[image]

This picture is my example. When I click in to list  item "Extensible and customizable by design" - Ckeditor has to scroll to current item position.

I don't have a code, because I don't understand how to start to solve my problem.